# Как лучше спроектировать индикацию состояния в Unity, C#

Tags: unity3d

Столкнулся со сверх тривиальной задачей, которая поставила меня в тупик. Есть 4 состояния, и есть некий прибор, который их отображает. В моем случае это классический селектор АКПП (без М режима). 4 состояния уже определены, их трогать нельзя. Если машина заведена, то горит одна из лампочек, а заглушена, то все лампочки не горят. И вот очень чешутся руки SOLID не нарушить. Первый способ, как это можно реализовать:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Core.Car
{
    public class TransmissionSelector : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private LightFixture _p;
        [SerializeField] private LightFixture _r;
        [SerializeField] private LightFixture _n;
        [SerializeField] private LightFixture _d;

        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public TransmissionMode TransmissionMode { get; set; }

        private void Update()
        {
            _p.SetLight(TransmissionMode == TransmissionMode.PARKING && Enabled);
            _r.SetLight(TransmissionMode == TransmissionMode.REVERSE && Enabled);
            _n.SetLight(TransmissionMode == TransmissionMode.NEUTRAL && Enabled);
            _d.SetLight(TransmissionMode == TransmissionMode.DRIVING && Enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Но данный код очень... прямолинейный. Хардкод. Никакой расширяемости.
Пришла в голову другая идея, сделать два скрипта, первый - это универсальный селектор, а второй - лампочка, которая помнит состояние, на которое она реагирует и состояние включенности.

Класс селектора:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Core.Car
{
    public class TransmissionSelector : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private TransmissionSelectorLamp[] _lamps;

        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public TransmissionMode TransmissionMode { get; set; }

        private void Update()
        {
            foreach (var lamp in _lamps)
            {
                lamp.Enabled = Enabled;
                lamp.CurrentMode = TransmissionMode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс лампочки:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Core.Car
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(LightFixture))]
    public class TransmissionSelectorLamp : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private TransmissionMode _mode;

        private LightFixture _lamp;

        public TransmissionMode CurrentMode { private get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { private get; set; }

        private void Awake()
        {
            _lamp = GetComponent<LightFixture>();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            _lamp.SetLight(_mode == CurrentMode && Enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

И вот в чем проблема. Лампочка теперь знает, на какой сигнал она загорается! Это ужасное архитектурное решение. Зато расширяемое.

Оба эти решения больны тем, что имеется данная запись:

```
TransmissionMode == SomeMode && Enabled
```

Здесь уже нарушение человеческой логики! В одном логическом выражении состояние включенности и сравнение состояния режима трансмиссии. Это как говорить, что "Я подпрыгну, если у тебя красное яблоко и свет включен". Нерационально.

Вопрос. Как быть? Какой вариант оставить? Или есть нормальное решение данного вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема почему это не `SOLID` не в `TransmissionMode == SomeMode && Enabled`, это полная фигня.

- нарушен фундаментальный принцип, `Single Responsobility`! Класс `TransmissionSelector` имеет ответственность состояния и визуализации лампочек, почему трансмиссия вообще в курсе о существовании какого-то там блока лампочек на приборной панели? Как в коде, так и в реальной жизни.
- `Update` обновляющий лампочки каждый кадр что бы что? 99% этих обновлений ничего не обновят, код просто толчит говно в ступе.
- у трансмиссии есть нейтралка, а `Enabled` это ваще чё? Не к лампочка ли это относится? Из-за нарушенной ответственности не ясно... Но даже если это так, то это скорее состояние электропитания авто, а не лично лампочек, что опять нарушает ответственность и вообще саму логику происходящего.

Одина ответственность - один класс:

- есть `Transmission`, которая по команде (методу, а не свойству) меняет состояние, свойство может быть `{ get; private set }` (`{ private get; set; }` быть не может от слова СОВСЕМ), не плохо было бы иметь `event` смены состояния! Класс по сути поле класса `Car`, `MonoBehaviour` ему быть не к чему.
- есть панель с лампочками, некий `TransmissionIndicator` и это чисто визуализация, соответственно модель и бизнесс логика о её существовании знать не можна. Все что он должен делать, подписаться на событие трансмиссии и менять состояние лампочек по факту изменения, а не долбиться каждый кадр.
- не `SOLID` все едино, нормальному неймингу посвящают не меньше времени. То что можно было бы назвать `TransmissionSelector` это ручка коробки передач, которая в игре тоже является исключительно визуализацией и не более, поскольку в архитектура кода, в отличие от реальности мы меняем передачу напрямую.

Comment: Да, вижу. На счет трансмиссии - отдельный класс был такой у машины. Зачем-то решил (для наглядности?) изобразить в виде свойств. Enabled - это да, электричество) Точно так же на деле является _car.Engine.State == EngineState.Working. Как раз с электричеством и сидел, вопрошая, как лучше. За события спасибо, не подумал их использовать сначала

Answer (score -3):

1. Зачем стороннее ПО LightFixture? В юнити сделан свой свет. Просто light :/
2. [SerializedField] private можно просто сократить до public
3. В си # в классе все по умолчанию private, private void Update - лишнее.
4. Первый вариант лучше, используйте switch. Его специально разработали для enum.
5. В юнити параметр enabled есть по умолчанию. Свой зачем добавлять?
6. Не надо в юнити солид тащить, юнити - это скрипт. Не надо программировать, надо скриптовать. В скриптах не имеет значения архитектура. Вы не делаете вычислительное ПО, где это важно.

```
    public class Akpp : MonoBehaviour{
        public GameObject p, r, n, d;
        public TransmissionMode TransmissionMode;

        void Update(){
            p.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = false;
            n.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = false;
            d.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = false;
            r.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = false;

            switch(TransmissionMode){
                case TransmissionMode.P:
                    p.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = true;
                    break;
                case TransmissionMode.D:
                    d.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = true;
                    break;
                case TransmissionMode.N:
                    n.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = true;
                    break;
                case TransmissionMode.R:
                    r.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: публичные поля - это полное нарушение принципа сокрытия, LightFixture - это класс, который позволяет плавно включать и выключать свет и настраивать его. Я не использую Light, это лампочка, которая просто должна визуально светиться и там вызывается эффект Blur из постпроцессинга, дописывать private - это код стайл си шарпа. Зачем каждый раз делать GetComponent<Light>, если можно просто сразу сделать поле этого типа Light. public Light a, b, c, d и тд. Enabled - это не юнитивский отключатель компонент, а внутриигровое состояние

Comment: Сокрытие в юнити... в блокноте, говорят, есть сокрытие. LightFixture: Велосипед еще раз сделал и назвал по-другому - горжусь, он не едет, а перемещается! Кодстайл в юнити - у них их СДК нарушает кодстайл си шарпа  тысячу и один раз. Про GetComponent<Light> - это примитивное получение поля из КОМПОЗИЦИИ классов. Вас, видать, таким словам не учили. Это скрипт. Просто список действий, оно даже не компилируется. Зачем выделываться атрибутами. Тем более вы пишите скрипт-реализацию. И хотите расширяемости в самом вопросе. Это реализация, Карл, получил значение и вызвал функцию - ВСЁ.

Comment: Вопрос вообще не про это. А как с точки зрения архитектуры сделать индикатор 4 состояний, который может отключать все 4 лампочки. Я в вопросе интересовался, как этот флаг сделать лучше, который Enabled, задача которого не отключать компоненту, а гасить все 4 лампы.

Comment: Ой-ой-ой. Я ввел флаг и называю это архитектурой четырех лампочек :"( Хотите - закостыльте nullable там. Будет ОЧЕНЬ красиво. А пока вы мыслите на уровне архитектуры флагов, так и пишите, на своем уровне. Не засоряйте этим интернет. За вас я уже написал код, что еще хотите? Нормальной архитектуры захотелось, так пишите с самого начала на тех языках, где есть std::optional. А пока - это уровень флагов и какого-нибудь хендлинга исключений при обработке одного значения энума

Comment: Без обид, вам есть еще чему поучиться. Если вы спрашиваете совета - бесполезно спорить. 
Вся архитектура в юнити пишется не в скриптах. Не в монобехавюрах. В реализации не надо никакой архитектуры